# Import RichText in Sharepoint list item

Tags: custom-list, import, rich-text, excel-import

I have to import to SharePoint lists data from a LotusNotes base. So, I exported the information in Excel, and there, matching the column names, I could import some simple data in lists.

However, in one list I have some RichText to import (text bold, italic, red, some pictures).

In what format should I store the RichText (in Excel?) in order to import it in SharePoint?

In what format the RichText is stored in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "multiple lines of text" column in SharePoint with the "Use enhanced rich text" option enabled in the column settings. This will allow you to import the rich text in to SharePoint. More information on column types can be found here:

[List and library column types and options](https://support.microsoft.com/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7)

**Edit:** Rich text refers to HTML.

Comment: I know how to create the column. In that column I need to import from excel. The question is what format should have the data in that Excel column. Should it be XML, HTML, RTF, DOC?

Comment: Rich text, refers to rich HTML. So it would be HTML.

Comment: HTML... what about the pictures?

Comment: Images are only referred to in HTML e.g. img src attributes etc. If you have rich HTML, then it should work the same as it does now.

Comment: OK, could you add these details in the answer (for future reference). I will try to export current data to HTML to be able to import in SharePoint via Excel. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: have clarified that rich text is HTML in my answer. As for how HTML works, that's beyond the scope of the answer/question.

Comment: thanks, question closed, but I have another one related :) https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303417/import-encoded-images-in-sharepoint-rich-text-html