# Import encoded images in SharePoint Rich text (HTML)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, import, rich-text, excel-import

I try to import RTF in SharePoint ListItem, like this
[image]

My `History` field contain some HTML, that I can open in a navigator without problems:

```
<br><font size=4 face="Verdana"><b>Rich Text Test Alternate Form</b></font>
<br>
<br><font size=2 face="Verdana"><b>Title:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;This
is a title field</font>
<br>
<hr>
<br><font size=2 face="Verdana"><b>Rich Text:</b></font>
<br><font size=2 face="Verdana">and this is </font><font size=3 face="Verdana"><u>rich</u></font><font size=2 face="Verdana">
</font><font size=2 color=red face="Verdana"><b><i>text</i></b></font>
<br>
<br><img alt="big picture" src="data:image/png;base64,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" style="border:0px solid;">
<br><tt><font size=2>thanks for playing</font></tt>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
  //8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
<br>
<br>
```

However all the `src="data:image/png;base64` is trimmed during the import (I import via ShareGate).

My SharePoint field is configured like this:

[image]

So, I get all the HTML, but without pictures:

[image]

the resulting HTML is like
[image]

Is there a way to add/keep encoded base64 pictures in SharePoint HTML fields?

Comment: Can you confirm that the column supports base64 images?

Comment: @CallumCrowley updated the OP, sorry for french :)

Comment: Can you test adding the content to the column via the SharePoint UI? To ensure it's not SharePoint removing the base64 images from your HTML?